# Highcharts - Gauges Versioning

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have included `solid-gauge` `highchart` in my application, with appropriate script files

```
highcharts.js
highcharts-more.js
solid-gauge.src.js
```

as mentioned in [Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/)

Currently I am using version `Highcharts 2.1.1`. Should I upgrade the version to `Highcharts 4.0.1` to use the `Highcharts-Gauges`?

Comment: Yes you need to update to the newest branch.

Comment: Can you please tell me the purpose of "highcharts-more.js" file? Should I include that if I upgrade the version to 4.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update to the newest branch.